# How to create mutually exclusive yes / no checkboxes + set default checkbox values

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, react-hook-form, form-library

I am trying to create a **react-hook-form** component that achieves the following:

- There are ***two checkboxes that cannot be checked at the same time***: A "yes" and a "no" checkbox. When a user clicks "yes", the "no" checkbox should not be checked and the value assigned to the default key should be "yes". When a user clicks "no" the opposite happens. How do use react-hook-form to implement two mutually exclusive checkboxes?
- ***If the user has checked a box during a previous session, one of the checkboxes will maintain the previously entered value*** (e.g., if during a first session the user checks "no", the user will see "no" checked when the page reloads). How do I ensure that the correct checkbox is checked when the user returns to the form? No matter what I've tried so far, both checkboxes are checked when I return to the form - whether a default value is assigned or not.
- ***Only one value***, a string (not an array) ***should be applied to the designated key***. (e.g., `{...otherKeysValues, key_name: "yes"}`). As of now, the values are returned as `{...otherKeyValues, key_name: ["yes"]}` or `{...otherKeyValues, key_name: ["yes", "no"]}` depending on my setup.

Here's a rough example of the code I'm working with:

```
function ComponentName({ fetchedData }) {
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, control, watch } = useForm({
    mode: 'onChange',
    defaultValues: fetchedData
  })

  const { fields, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: "fetchedData"
  })



  useEffect(() => {
...fetch data
    reset(fetchedData)
  }, [reset, fetchedData])


const onSubmit = data => console.log(data)

const watchOption = watch('key_name')

return (
  <Form
    onChange={() => console.log("watch, getValues()", watchOption, getValues())}
    onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
  >
    <Col>
      <Form.Check
        className="checkbox-text pl-3"
        inline
        label="Yes"
        value={'yes'}
        ref={register}
        defaultChecked={'yes'}
        name={'key_name'}
        onClick={() => reset({ 'key_name': 'yes' })}

      />

      <Form.Check
        label="No"
        value={'no'}
        ref={register}
        defaultChecked={'no'}
        name={'key_name'}
        onClick={() => reset({ 'key_name': 'no' })}

      />
              </Form>
```

Comment: Mutually exclusive checkboxes? You should use radio buttons.

Comment: The use case requires yes / no checkboxes due to client preference.

Comment: You can make radio buttons look however you like with some CSS trickery. They can look like checkboxes or flying unicorns.